# Pine Script, If issue

Tags: pine-script

I have problem to rune below code, did you can help me to solve?

```
if wt1 < 5 and wt1 > -5
plot(cross(wt1, wt2) ? wt2 : na, color = black , style = circles, linewidth = 4)
plot(cross(wt1, wt2) ? wt2 : na, color = (wt2 - wt1 > 0 ? red : lime) , style = circles, linewidth = 4)

else if wt1 > 53 and wt2 > 53
plot(cross(wt1, wt2) ? wt2 : na, color = black , style = circles, linewidth = 4)
plot(cross(wt1, wt2) ? wt2 : na, color = (wt2 - wt1 > 0 ? red : lime) , style = circles, linewidth = 4)

else if wt1 < -53 and wt2 < -53
plot(cross(wt1, wt2) ? wt2 : na, color = black , style = circles, linewidth = 4)
plot(cross(wt1, wt2) ? wt2 : na, color = (wt2 - wt1 > 0 ? red : lime) , style = circles, linewidth = 4)

else
na
```

Comment: Do you still need help on this question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a telepath, but I'll try to guess that you have a problem with spaces in the operator `if`

```
if wt1 < 5 and wt1 > -5
    plot(cross(wt1, wt2) ? wt2 : na, color = black , style = circles, linewidth = 4)
    plot(cross(wt1, wt2) ? wt2 : na, color = (wt2 - wt1 > 0 ? red : lime) , style = circles, linewidth = 4)

else if wt1 > 53 and wt2 > 53
    plot(cross(wt1, wt2) ? wt2 : na, color = black , style = circles, linewidth = 4)
    plot(cross(wt1, wt2) ? wt2 : na, color = (wt2 - wt1 > 0 ? red : lime) , style = circles, linewidth = 4)

else if wt1 < -53 and wt2 < -53
    plot(cross(wt1, wt2) ? wt2 : na, color = black , style = circles, linewidth = 4)
    plot(cross(wt1, wt2) ? wt2 : na, color = (wt2 - wt1 > 0 ? red : lime) , style = circles, linewidth = 4)

else
    na
```

Comment: It's not working, Error: no viable alternative at input 'if'. Try to add line '//@version=2' to the top of your script

Comment: Please provide a full script to investigate.